# voice recording and play programatically in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-simulator

Is it possible in blackberry to record voice and play it programatically.
Please give me some idea the how can we achieve this.
Any reference link too if possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

**- Record Code**

```
Player player = Manager.createPlayer("capture://audio?encoding=amr");

RecordControl recorder = (RecordControl)player.getControl("RecordControl");

recorder.setRecordLocation("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/Music/recordingFile.amr");

recorder.startRecord();

player.start();

Thread.sleep(5000);

recorder.commit();

player.close();
```

**- Play Code**

```
Player music = Manager.createPlayer("file:///SDCard/BlackBerry/Music/Musicfile.mp3");
music.realize();
music.start();
```

Comment: I think you have given me the code for audio recording .......I am looking voice recording ....